# Display Name instead of ID in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, php-7.4

I have two tables: User and Organisation. User contains foreign key organisation_id referencing organisation. For viewing user, it shows error 'Trying to get property 'name' of non object.

UserController

```
 public function view($id)
 {
  $record = User::find($id);
  return view('user.view',compact('record'));
 }
```

User.php

```
public function getOrg()
{
return $this->belongsTo(Organisation::class);
}
```

View.blade.php

```
<tr>
 <th>Organisation</th>
 <td>{{ $record->organisation_id->name }}</td>
</tr>
```

Try to refer another question and answer but still can't solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `User.php` your method name should be `oranisation` instead of `getOrg`. Laravel calls this method `organisation()` behind the scenes when accessing the `$user->organisation` property.

```php
public function organisation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Organisation::class, 'organisation_id', 'id');
}
```

Then in `view.blade.php` a slight tweak:

```html
<tr>
 <th>Organisation</th>
 <td>{{ $record->organisation->name }}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your UserController does not have any bugs in it. However, consider using [Implicit Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding) to automatically fetch your User as an argument in your UserController method *after you have gotten the rest of your code working.*

Second, your User.php isn't defining the relationship according to Laravel's convention and I think that is a source of the problem. Prefer, instead, the following:

```
public function organisation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Organisation::class);
}
```

The `organisation()` method utilizes a "magic" method that allows you to fetch the full Eloquent model of the relationship using the following in `view.blade.php`:

```
<tr>
    <th>Organisation</th>
    <td>{{ $record->organisation->name }}</td>
</tr>
```

Your code breaks for the following reasons:

- $record->organization_id is referring to the actual number in the db, not the related model. To get the related model in your example, you would need to do $record->getOrg(). However, for reasons stated above, you should rename that method to make better use of Laravel's conventions.
- Additionally, methods that begin with get...() are considered *accessors* to additional model attributes not found in the DB. So try to avoid using them for simple relationships.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: where can i know the documentation for the method that utilizes a 'magic' method like you said if you don't mind ?

Answer (score 0):

you have define the relation in the query

```
public function view($id)
{
  $record = User::with('getOrg')->find($id)->first();
  return view('user.view',compact('record'));
}
```

In View

```
 <tr>
  <th>Organisation</th>
  <td>{{ $record->getOrg->name }}</td>
 </tr>
```

Try this way

Comment: it shows error..trying to get property 'name' of non-object.. getOrg method is not suitable for making a relationship with another model like anyone said in this topic

Comment: can you use dd($record) in the controller is getting data in query you can check